# How to use 'crypto' module in Angular2?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I install module:

```
npm install --save crypto
```

I import it to my component:

```
import { createHmac } from "crypto";
```

But I get error:

> ERROR in -------------- (4,28): Canno
>   t find module 'crypto'.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I am developing with the latest versions of Angular and 'crypto-js' seems to work fine.

Install the package and the definitions:

```
npm install crypto-js
npm install --save @types/crypto-js
```

Use it:

```
import { SHA256, enc } from "crypto-js";
...
login() {
...
   const hashedPass = SHA256(this.loginForm.value.password).toString(enc.Hex);
...
}
```

Comment: great solution.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the definition files for a 3rd party library like `crypto`. So that typescript can find the "meaning" for it.

I think the definition file is:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/crypto-js
```

Then you can import the module like:

```
import * as crypto from "crypto";
```

If you can't find the definition file for that lib, you can write it on your own or as a workaround you can declare the module as `any` but typescript won't be able to auto-complete the methods.

```
declare var crypto: any;
```

and use its methods like:

```
crypto.createHmac..
```

Comment: But I think [crypto-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js) is a different module than [crypto](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto).

Comment: @johnerfx ah thanks for the feedback, you can declare the module as any or create its definition file on your own. I'll edit my answer with an example.

Comment: thanks for the answers, but I still can't make it work: ERROR TypeError: crypto.createHmac is not a function

Comment: @johnerfx if you are using systemjs did you include it in your imports? or your index.html? or if you are using angular-cli did you include it in your scripts? I got to go now but I will check it again in the morning.

Answer (score 1):

The [current **tsconfig.json** configuration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) (I'm using "typescript": "~3.5.3") includes a *types* compiler option that should be used in this case: In tsconfig.ts file add the following:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types" : [ "node" ]
   }
}
```

Import the library where you want to use it with `import crypto from 'crypto'`

Don't use import * as crypto from 'crypto': it will import deprecated symbols/functions. (you should probably see the compiler complain about it)