# Getting error Cannot find module 'crypto'

Tags: node.js, cryptography, cryptojs

I am trying to use node Crypto module in Angular 7 for asymmetric encryption.
and used below command to import the Crypto module

```
import * as crypto from 'crypto';
```

but still I am getting error that is

```
`ERROR in src/app/log-in/log-in.component.ts(11,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'crypto'.`
```

Please help me to resolve the error that how to use this library into Angular.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you trying with crypto or crypto-js? I don't think crypto is out there anymore.

Comment: crypto only but it is included in node module

Comment: Might be this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43353718/how-to-use-crypto-module-in-angular2

Comment: @comprex Used your shaed link but not useful thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the author on npm , The crypto package is no longer available as it is now built in to Node.js. I would suggest looking for an alternative. I came across a Github Gist that contains some suggestions: https://gist.github.com/jo/8619441

Make sure whatever you pick is useable in the browser. Some of the options listed there are server-side only.

Comment: There some Links which are help full in this: node-rsa: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rsa
Quick-Encrypt: https://www.npmjs.com/package/quick-encrypt
asymmetric-crypto: https://www.npmjs.com/package/asymmetric-crypto

Answer (score 8):

I was trying to import { randomBytes } from "crypto"; then such error occurred,
I installed node types `npm install @types/node --save-dev` and it was resolved.

Comment: This is only relevant if you are using Typescript, which the OP did not indicate.

Comment: @Ibragile, Angular uses TypeScript by default, so is implied by the OP

Answer (score -3):

Make sure that you install 'crypto' module from npm

use: `npm i crypto` to install this module.

for more information please visit [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto).

If this is still not working then you have to check for alternative module because this module is dedicated you can check [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-crypto)

Comment: There is any error while installing module? because this module dedicated you can also use angular-crypto : https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-crypto