# error TS2307: Cannot find module 'crypto'

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

Im writting a web with Angular 6. I need to hash a string client-side, so i'm using [createHash("sha256") from 'crypto'](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createhash_algorithm_options).

actually, I just wrote createHash and vscode suggest me the import, which looks like this:

```
import { createHash } from "crypto";
```

(this way of importing seems to be fine, and it's used in some typescript tutorial, [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html)) and then:

```
var hashed = createHash("sha256").update(data).digest()
```

all syntax is being suggested by vscode, with docstrings and everything. But at the moment of compile with `npm start` I get:

```
ERROR in src/domain/User.ts(2,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'crypto'.
```

as far as I could understand, `crypto` is now built-in into node, and I shouldn't have any problem importing it.

also notice that if I run `node` in terminal to open a REPL, entering 'crypto' gives me an output that suggest that everything works well.

Here are the versions of everything I think that cares:

```
node --version: v10.15.1
ng --version:
Angular CLI: 6.2.9
Node: 10.15.1
OS: linux x64
Angular: 6.1.10
typescript 2.9.2
webpack 4.16.4
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: did you include `crypto js` in your *angular.json*?

Answer (score 29):

For Typescript 2.* and Angular 2+ -

1. Install and add this package to the devDependencies.

   ```
   npm install @types/node --save-dev
   ```
2. In tsconfig.app.json under the compilerOptions, add this -

   ```
   "types": [ "node" ],
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the dependency. There was the same question, try to do the same, it must help [How to use 'crypto' module in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43353718/how-to-use-crypto-module-in-angular2)

Comment: Yes, I've been there. But note that there is not selected answer. Notice [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43353718/how-to-use-crypto-module-in-angular2#comment73770954_43353846) about first answer.
I've tried second answer without success. Thanks

Comment: There is an issue about that on github https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1548#issuecomment-286151056 Unfortunately, crypto is not supported as a native client-side module yet. Module crypto-browserify contains createHash, check, if it is appropriate for you. It installs as a regular dependency and shouldn't cause serious troubles.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.  The first solution I found was to add the following to `packages.json`

```
"browser": {
    "crypto": false
}
```

Since all I wanted was to generate a sha256 digest to use a an index I removed `crypto-js` and `@types/crypto=js` and replaced it with `jshashed`.

```
yarn add jshashes
```

I then modified my digest service to reflect the new library:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as JsHashes  from 'jshashes';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class CryptoService {
  getSha256HEX(value: string): string {
     const hash =  new JsHashes.SHA256;
     return hash.hex(value);
  }
}
```

Simply add `CryptoService` to your module file `apps.module.ts`

```
import { CryptoService }  from '@services/crypto.service';
```

Note: The `@services` path defined in `tsconfig.json`

All that is left is to declaref `CryptoService` in the constructor were needed:

```
constructor( private _crypto: CryptoService; ) {}
```

and use it by passing a string, or if compound  data (like and HTTP query string to build a cache key) stringify it.

```
 myHash = this._crypto.getSha256HEX(JSON.stringify(_compoundDataStruccture));
```

Note: [jshashes](https://github.com/h2non/jshashes) supports

Digests:

- MD5
- SHA1
- SHA256
- SHA512
- HMAC
- RIPEND-160

Also:

- Base64 encoding/decoding
- CRC-32 calculation
- UTF-8 encoding/decoding

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a server side application for NodeJs using typescript then you simply need to install @types/node using `npm i @types/node -D` and then you should be able to import it using `import * as crypto from "crypto"`