# Adding File to Azure Storage Blob from Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to figure out how to upload an image using [ngx-awesome-uploader](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-awesome-uploader?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsimple-demo%2Fsimple-demo.component.css) to azure storage blob from Angular.

I'd like to be able to send it directly to azure storage blob from angular using this library. I've been able to send it to my nodejs backend no problem, but it's been challenging for me to send it directly to blob storage instead. Can anyone provide a working example of how to do this? I appreciate any help!

`Choose Simple Demo in stackblitz. Not Advanced Demo`

[Stackblitz example of ngx awesome uploader](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-awesome-uploader?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsimple-demo%2Fsimple-demo.component.css)

The file is passed to this. (Console output below code)

```
import { FilePreviewModel } from 'ngx-awesome-uploader';
import { HttpRequest, HttpClient, HttpEvent, HttpEventType } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { FilePickerAdapter } from 'ngx-awesome-uploader';

export class DemoFilePickerAdapter extends FilePickerAdapter {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    super();
  }
  public uploadFile(fileItem: FilePreviewModel) {
    const form = new FormData();
    form.append('file', fileItem.file);

   console.log("FILE OUTPUT");
    console.log(fileItem.file);


//need to replace everything below with code to add to storage blob

    const api = 'https://demo-file-uploader.free.beeceptor.com';
    const req = new HttpRequest('POST', api, form, {reportProgress: true});
    return this.http.request(req)
    .pipe(
      map( (res: HttpEvent<any>) => {
          if (res.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
          return res.body.id.toString();
        } else if (res.type ===  HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
            // Compute and show the % done:
            const UploadProgress = +Math.round((100 * res.loaded) / res.total);
            return UploadProgress;
        }
      })
      );
  }

}
```

the console.output of FILE OUTPUT is

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-javascript-client-libraries#upload-blobs

Comment: This code snippet is confusing to me. Can you show me an example with the stackblitz I linked?

Comment: @user6680 - please edit your question to contain any/all relevant code, rather than asking people to click through to a link. Links-to-code are discouraged, since links can rot/die/disappear, then future readers have no reference. It's important to include all specifics in your question, including the area in which you're having the problem, errors, expected vs actual outcome, etc.

Comment: Sorry about that. I added additional information to my question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to my test,  if you want to upload file to Azure blob, please refer to the following steps

1. install Azure storage SDk

```
npm install @azure/storage-blob
```

2. Update app.component.html File

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="file">Choose File</label>
  <input type="file"
         id="file"
         (change)="onFileChange($event)">
</div>
```

4. Update Environment.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  accountName : "<account name>",
  containerName:"",
   key:""
};
```

5. Add the following code in polyfills.ts

```
(window as any).global = window;
(window as any).process = require( 'process' );
(window as any).Buffer = require( 'buffer' ).Buffer;
```

6. Add the following code in app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {BlobServiceClient,AnonymousCredential,newPipeline } from '@azure/storage-blob';
import { environment } from './../environments/environment';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'web1';
  currentFile : File =null;
  onFileChange(event) {
    this.currentFile = event.target.files[0];
   console.log(this.currentFile.name)
    console.log(this.currentFile.type)
// generate account sas token
  const accountName =environment.accountName;
  const key=environment.key;
  const start = new Date(new Date().getTime() - (15 * 60 * 1000));
  const end = new Date(new Date().getTime() + (30 * 60 * 1000));
const signedpermissions = 'rwdlac';
  const signedservice = 'b';
  const signedresourcetype = 'sco';
  const signedexpiry = end.toISOString().substring(0, end.toISOString().lastIndexOf('.')) + 'Z';
  const signedProtocol = 'https';
  const signedversion = '2018-03-28';

  const StringToSign =
      accountName+ '\n' +
      signedpermissions + '\n' +
      signedservice + '\n' +
      signedresourcetype + '\n' +
       '\n' +
      signedexpiry + '\n' +
       '\n' +
      signedProtocol + '\n' +
signedversion + '\n';
  const crypto =require('crypto')
   const sig = crypto.createHmac('sha256', Buffer.from(key, 'base64')).update(StringToSign, 'utf8').digest('base64');
  const sasToken =`sv=${(signedversion)}&ss=${(signedservice)}&srt=${(signedresourcetype)}&sp=${(signedpermissions)}&se=${encodeURIComponent(signedexpiry)}&spr=${(signedProtocol)}&sig=${encodeURIComponent(sig)}`;
  const containerName=environment.containerName;
  
            const pipeline =newPipeline (new AnonymousCredential(),{
            retryOptions: { maxTries: 4 }, // Retry options
            userAgentOptions: { userAgentPrefix: "AdvancedSample V1.0.0" }, // Customized telemetry string
            keepAliveOptions: {
                // Keep alive is enabled by default, disable keep alive by setting false
                enable: false
            }
            });
   
            const blobServiceClient =new BlobServiceClient(`https://${accountname}.blob.core.windows.net?${sasToken}`,
                                                             pipeline  )
            const containerClient =blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName)
            if(!containerClient.exists()){
            console.log("the container does not exit")
            await containerClient.create()

            }
            const client = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(this.currentFile.name)
           const response = await client.uploadBrowserData(this.currentFile,{
                  blockSize: 4 * 1024 * 1024, // 4MB block size
                  concurrency: 20, // 20 concurrency
                  onProgress: (ev) => console.log(ev),
                  blobHTTPHeaders :{blobContentType:this.currentFile.type}
                  })
    console.log(response._response.status)
 }
}
```

7. [Configure CORS for Azure storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/cross-origin-resource-sharing--cors--support-for-the-azure-storage-services)

```
Allowed origins: *
Allowed verbs: DELETE,GET,HEAD,MERGE,POST,OPTIONS,PUT
Allowed headers: *
Exposed headers: *
Maximum age (seconds): 86400
```

8. Test. I upload a pdf file
   [image]
   [image]

---

Regarding how to configure CORS, please refer to the following steps

1. Sign in [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/).
2. Select the Azure account you use
3. Configure CORS

[image]

---

## Update

If you cannot use function `createHmac`, you can try to use `crypto-js`. The detailed steps are as below

1. install sdk

```
npm install crypto-js --save
npm install @types/crypto-js --save-dev
```

2. Update code in the in app.component.ts

```
...
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';


...
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'web1';
  currentFile : File =null;
  onFileChange(event) {
    this.currentFile = event.target.files[0];
   console.log(this.currentFile.name)
    console.log(this.currentFile.type)
// generate account sas token
  const accountName =environment.accountName;
  const key=environment.key;
  const start = new Date(new Date().getTime() - (15 * 60 * 1000));
  const end = new Date(new Date().getTime() + (30 * 60 * 1000));
const signedpermissions = 'rwdlac';
  const signedservice = 'b';
  const signedresourcetype = 'sco';
  const signedexpiry = end.toISOString().substring(0, end.toISOString().lastIndexOf('.')) + 'Z';
  const signedProtocol = 'https';
  const signedversion = '2018-03-28';

  const StringToSign =
      accountName+ '\n' +
      signedpermissions + '\n' +
      signedservice + '\n' +
      signedresourcetype + '\n' +
       '\n' +
      signedexpiry + '\n' +
       '\n' +
      signedProtocol + '\n' +
signedversion + '\n';

 var str =CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(StringToSign,CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(key));
 var sig = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(str);
 
 
  const sasToken =`sv=${(signedversion)}&ss=${(signedservice)}&srt=${(signedresourcetype)}&sp=${(signedpermissions)}&se=${encodeURIComponent(signedexpiry)}&spr=${(signedProtocol)}&sig=${encodeURIComponent(sig)}`;
  const containerName=environment.containerName;

            const pipeline =newPipeline (new AnonymousCredential(),{
            retryOptions: { maxTries: 4 }, // Retry options
            userAgentOptions: { userAgentPrefix: "AdvancedSample V1.0.0" }, // Customized telemetry string
            keepAliveOptions: {
                // Keep alive is enabled by default, disable keep alive by setting false
                enable: false
            }
            });

            const blobServiceClient =new BlobServiceClient(`https://${accountname}.blob.core.windows.net?${sasToken}`,
                                                             pipeline  )
            const containerClient =blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName)
            if(!containerClient.exists()){
            console.log("the container does not exit")
            await containerClient.create()

            }
            const client = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(this.currentFile.name)
           const response = await client.uploadBrowserData(this.currentFile,{
                  blockSize: 4 * 1024 * 1024, // 4MB block size
                  concurrency: 20, // 20 concurrency
                  onProgress: (ev) => console.log(ev),
                  blobHTTPHeaders :{blobContentType:this.currentFile.type}
                  })
    console.log(response._response.status)
 }
}
```

Comment: I've integrated you're code and I've gotten rid of ngx-awesome-uploader due to how it's designed. Getting rid of this library has made things easier for me with handling the file. I'm now using a different image uploader/cropper that when I hit confirm image, it stores the image as a base64 type. I've added your code, but I'm getting a CORS error. I know you mention CORS in your answer, but I don't understand where I'm supposed to add CORS in angular.  ```Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)```

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for clarifying. I have one other issue that that I've been trying to solve. CORS was the issue at first, but now it's saying ```crypto.createHmac is not a function``` Didn't know you could reference nodejs module ```const crypto = require('crypto')``` I tried installing npm i crypto --save, but it the only thing in there is a package.json file and readme file. package.json file : https://pastebin.com/xrXPeFTe   I tried this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43353846/4350389 , but it gives me same error even though it recognizes function: https://postimg.cc/zytTWn97 Any ideas?

Comment: @user6680 Could you please tell me your angular version?

Comment: it's Angular: 8.2.8

Comment: @user6680 Could you please try to use ```import {createHmac} from 'crypto'```?

Comment: I imported it but ```'createHmac' is declared but its value is never read``` if I hover over declaration.

Comment: @user6680 Please try to run ```npm install crypto``` then use ```import {createHmac} from 'crypto'``` https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOyzh.png

Comment: I did that and it can see the createHmac function https://postimg.cc/9rw7zJTY   but the crypto module is using the require library https://postimg.cc/vDc1S3Pw  same error

Comment: Please try to remove these two lines code and directly use the ```createHmac``` function  https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtekH.png and   https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwPnZ.png

Comment: Gotcha. I'm not getting that error anymore, but it's now saying ```"Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function``` The error is being thrown by the ```const sig``` line. I added a ```return;``` before it no error. After the ```const sig``` line, the error comes up. Here's my updated code: https://pastebin.com/7N1Uf2Mr

Comment: @user6680 Could you please provide the detailed error message

Comment: @user6680 According to my test, we also need to use ```var crypto = require('crypto')
      crypto.createHmac()```.

Comment: it is a built-in Node module.

Comment: If it's a built in module, wouldn't this work? https://postimg.cc/p98jk08H @types/node? Also in your answer you said to put the code in app.component.ts. I put it in a component I created, but I doubt that matters, right? Also what if we tried using ```crypto-js```? I see it doesn't have the exact ```createHmac()``` function, but it looks like it has something similar? I've tried all the answers from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43353718/how-to-use-crypto-module-in-angular2/43353846#43353846  , but none of them work so I'm not really sure at this point

Comment: Hey Jim. Letting you know I just made a separate post for the ```createHmac is not a function``` issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60578019/crypto-createhmac-is-not-a-function-angular

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much. I have one other quick question though. I added the file successfully, but when I try to open it, it says it's doesn't support file type when trying to view it in windows Photos viewer. Pretty sure it's because of content-type. https://postimg.cc/NKwQ2mbf   I changed this line to reflect output in storage btw ```const client = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient("MYFILE.png")```  Any suggestions?

Comment: I tried ```blobHTTPHeaders: { blobContentType: "image/png" }``` or       ```blobHTTPHeaders: { blobContentType: "image/jpg" }``` but when I try to open/donwload it from storage explorer, it says https://postimg.cc/gXf34Jts

Comment: @user6680 According to my test, it is ok for me. If  I set content-type, I can see the picture on Azure Portal :   https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWz6U.png  and 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZhpx.png
  and  https://i.stack.imgur.com/YR3DZ.png

Comment: You're file format appears to be different than mine. Mine is base64 https://postimg.cc/hXXyhL1X. I did the first example in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38936042/4350389 and converted it to image. Uploaded to blob and now I can see the image. Thanks for everything!

Comment: I have one recommendation though as an edit for your code for future readers. Since it's using async/await, currently if the container doesn't exist, it will not hit the if condition and create the container. I got that part working by doing the following: https://pastebin.com/2c3NEhQi

Comment: Great demo. Question, `var str =CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(StringToSign,CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(key));` already sign `str`, why continue with `var sig = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(str);`? Do we verify it for every request?