# crypto.createHmac is not a function + angular

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, cryptography

I'm trying to get the crypto library working in order to use the specific method `createHmac` The goal is to use it in order to upload images to azure storage blob. [related post I made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60533341/adding-file-to-azure-storage-blob-from-angular)
, but I keep getting `crypto.createHmac is not a function` There's a related post to my issue 
[How to use 'crypto' module in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43353718/how-to-use-crypto-module-in-angular2) , but I've tried every answer in that post and I'm still having issues. I'm not sure how to get past this. I appreciate any help!

```
import { BlobServiceClient, AnonymousCredential, newPipeline } from '@azure/storage-blob';



  async addImagesToBlob() {


    let currentFile = this.file[0];

    const accountName = environment.accountName;
    const key = environment.key;
    const start = new Date(new Date().getTime() - (15 * 60 * 1000));
    const end = new Date(new Date().getTime() + (30 * 60 * 1000));
    const signedpermissions = 'rwdlac';
    const signedservice = 'b';
    const signedresourcetype = 'sco';
    const signedexpiry = end.toISOString().substring(0, end.toISOString().lastIndexOf('.')) + 'Z';
    const signedProtocol = 'https';
    const signedversion = '2018-03-28';

    const StringToSign =
      accountName + '\n' +
      signedpermissions + '\n' +
      signedservice + '\n' +
      signedresourcetype + '\n' +
      '\n' +
      signedexpiry + '\n' +
      '\n' +
      signedProtocol + '\n' +
      signedversion + '\n';
    const crypto = require('crypto');


    let sig = crypto.createHmac('sha256', Buffer.from(key, 'base64')).update(StringToSign, 'utf8').digest('base64');


    const sasToken = `sv=${(signedversion)}&ss=${(signedservice)}&srt=${(signedresourcetype)}&sp=${(signedpermissions)}&se=${encodeURIComponent(signedexpiry)}&spr=${(signedProtocol)}&sig=${encodeURIComponent(sig)}`;
    const containerName = environment.containerName;

    const pipeline = newPipeline(new AnonymousCredential(), {
      retryOptions: { maxTries: 4 }, // Retry options
      userAgentOptions: { userAgentPrefix: "AdvancedSample V1.0.0" }, // Customized telemetry string
      keepAliveOptions: {
        // Keep alive is enabled by default, disable keep alive by setting false
        enable: false
      }
    });
    const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(`https://${accountName}.blob.core.windows.net?${sasToken}`,
      pipeline)
    const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName)
    if (!containerClient.exists()) {
      console.log("the container does not exit")
      await containerClient.create()

    }
    const client = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(currentFile.name)
    const response = await client.uploadBrowserData(currentFile, {
      blockSize: 4 * 1024 * 1024, // 4MB block size
      concurrency: 20, // 20 concurrency
      onProgress: (ev) => console.log(ev),
      blobHTTPHeaders: { blobContentType: currentFile.type }
    })
    console.log(response._response.status);
  }
```

Answer (score -3):

Following Steps resolved my issue:

1. `npm install crypto-js --save`
2. `npm install @types/node --save`
3. `import { Crypto } from 'crypto-js'`
4. `Crypto.createHmac()` -> Notice '***`Crypto`***' and not '***`crypto`***' when calling `createHmac()`.